# ¿Como puedo comparar un txt con un excel y que este txt se recorra linea por linea?

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Con un macro que hice puedo perfectamente pasar un txt a excel desde una ruta a eleccion. El problema surge que dentro de la funcion EOF para poder llegar al final de el txt conozco solamente dos instrucciones Line input e Input. Ambas me leen linea por linea el txt y yo lo que deseo es que me lea palabra por palabra para que las compare con datos que se encuetran en un excel.

Trate de comentar el codigo lo maximo posible para que se entendiera

```
    Sub leerArchivoTextoCondicional()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim archivo As String  'ruta y nombre del archivo
     Dim buscar As String   'palabra a buscar dentro del texto 
    Dim texto As String    'línea de texto a leer
    Dim nLinea As Integer   'número de línea leída
    Dim fila As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook
     Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim libro As String
    Dim cuit As String

      libro = "Cruces" & ".xls"
      tmp = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.DropDowns("Drop Down 8").List (ActiveSheet.DropDowns("Drop Down 8").ListIndex)
tmp2 = Left(tmp, 4)


      'Abrir el archivo
       archivo = "C:\Users\rnovas002\Desktop\Shotting stars.txt"
       numerodearchivo = FreeFile ' el freefile busca numero libre de archivo
     Open archivo For Input As #numerodearchivo 'leer un archivo de texto por el canal #1

     cuit = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cartera 1").Range("d16").Value
     flag = 0
    nLinea = 1

  'Leer y procesar el contenido del archivo
      While Not EOF(nLinea) 'la función EOF regresa verdadero al llegar al final del  archivo
      Input #numerodearchivo, texto  'lee cada una de las líneas del archivo y las almacena en la variable texto (aca esta el porblema)


     If InStr(1, texto, cuit) > 0 Then 'buscar la palabra    en                    la línea del texto  leída
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Cartera 1").Range("d16").Offset(0, 1).Value =   ChrW(&H2713)
    End If
     If InStr(1, texto, tmp2) > 0 Then
      activeworbook.Sheets("Cartera 1").Range("j28").Value = ChrW(&H2713)
     End If
    Wend



Seek nLinea, 1 'vuelve a la primera linea

'Cerrar el archivo de entrada
Close #1

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cartera 1").Delete
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Mmmm... La función `InSrt`por defecto, utiliza `vbBinaryCompare ` si no me equivoco. Es decir, que distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas. Si utilizas `vbTextCompare `, entonces no se distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas. ¿Podría ser eso el problema? Otra opción que veo es, ya que estás comparando palabras, llévate las palabras a un array, y entonces comparas cada index del array con la palabra que estás buscando.

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio !!!!!!